# Fixed "Every derived table must have its own alias" now getting column doesn't exist error

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I'm trying to make this query work. Sorry I'm new to mysql.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mutamba_posts 
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT aluno_id FROM mutamba_amigos GROUP BY aluno_id) 
        ON mutamba_amigos.aluno_id  = mutamba_posts.post_aluno_id 
        WHERE mutamba_amigos.amizade_id IN (SELECT amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos WHERE aluno_id = '{$myid}')
        ORDER BY mutamba_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
```

getting the error: `Every derived table must have its own alias`

I changed it to :

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM mutamba_posts 
           INNER JOIN ( SELECT aluno_id  AS aluno_id, amizade_id as amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos GROUP BY aluno_id) 
           aluno_id ON mutamba_amigos.aluno_id  = mutamba_posts.post_aluno_id 
           WHERE mutamba_amigos.amizade_id IN (SELECT amizade_id AS amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos WHERE aluno_id = '{$myid}')
           ORDER BY mutamba_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
```

Now I'm getting the error: " Unknown column 'mutamba_amigos.amizade_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"

Any help please?

Comment: You need to give your subquery an alias...

Comment: may be because of alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give an alias name to every temp table from a subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM mutamba_posts 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT aluno_id 
   FROM mutamba_amigos
   WHERE mutamba_amigos.amizade_id IN 
   (
      SELECT amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos WHERE aluno_id = '{$myid}'
   )
   GROUP BY aluno_id
) mutamba_amigos ON mutamba_amigos.aluno_id  = mutamba_posts.post_aluno_id     
ORDER BY mutamba_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but I'm still getting the "Unknown column 'mutamba_amigos.amizade_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"

Comment: Added the `where` clause to the inner query

Answer (score 0):

Your first inner join subquery, you assigned an alias of "aluno_id" which I don't think you meant.  I think the restructure of your query would be simplified to...

```
SELECT
      mp.* 
   FROM 
      mutamba_posts mp
         JOIN mutamba_amigos ma
            ON mp.post_aluno_id = ma.aluno_id
   WHERE
      mp.post_aluno_id = '{$myid}'
   ORDER BY 
      mp.post_date DESC 
   LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}
```

In summary, your query was starting with the POSTS table, then looking into the AMIGOS table by the "aluno_id" to get AMIZADE_ID.  But then you use the AMIZADE_ID back to the AMIGOS table by it's "aluno_id". So, it appears you are looking for any posts that are by the person "aluno_id" provided order by the DATE(desc).  It looks like you were double-qualifying records to get back to the original underlying "aluno_id" value.

For the future, for things like this, you should try to post some sample data of each and show a sample of what you are trying to get out.  Simple (even abbreviated) table structures of respective columns in the query, and data with spaces between columns as tabs don't work well.